# Getting error in Entity Framework at SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework

I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

```
dbContext.Productos.Add(producto);
dbContext.Entry(producto).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Any idea about what is wrong here?

Thanks.

My stack trace is:

```
[OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source) +232
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +493
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut) +32
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) +272
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update() +143
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35() +34
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +448
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +219
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27() +71
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +213
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +408
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +320

[DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +366
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +56
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +52
   Clase5.Data.ProductoRepositorio.Insertar(Producto producto) in c:\Users\Juan\Downloads\Clase_5_-_Codigo_fuente\Clase5\Clase4\Data\ProductoRepositorio.cs:27
   Clase5.Controllers.ProductoController.TresCrearProducto(Producto producto) in c:\Users\Juan\Downloads\Clase_5_-_Codigo_fuente\Clase5\Clase4\Controllers\ProductoController.cs:43
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: remove this line: dbContext.Entry(producto).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

Comment: @codebased Still the same error..

Comment: Need to do see if it is really happening for producto or you are trying to save more than one object?

Comment: The first line you did `Productos.Add(producto)` the second line you did `Entry(producto).State = EntityState.Modified`, you wanted to add a new entity or modify existing entity, which is it?

Comment: @codebased Here is the link to download all the files..can you see if you can get the error, please? I've read every single line and can't deal with it.. https://mega.co.nz/#!B8tx0JzQ!e6bqkeb7N-NJeO9Ke41sHXcZzro3Q3oH8FX6B4TbdPE

Comment: @YuliamChandra I want to set it as modified. Then, when I Save Changes, all the modified data is saved again (That's the only reason to make it 'modified'). It's like an update.

Comment: I have similar issue, have you found where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented a field level concurrency in `Producto` entity. Go to the EDMX designer of your `Producto` entity. Go through properties of each column one by one. Select the column in the visual entity designer -> Press F4. Check the value of the property `Concurrency Mode`. It should be set to None. Have a look at below snapshot as sample for one of my entities `Employee`. If for any of the columns, you see the value as `Fixed` then that's the root cause of your error.

If you are really thinking of doing field level concurrency then use `RowVersion` instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false? If you have done that,please call DetectChanges manually before  SaveChanges, don't change the Entry State directly.